# CSS nth Selectors table rows

Tags: css

I want to target the following rows with CSS:

```
<tr class="r0"> *this one*
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1"> *this one*
<tr class="r1">
<tr class="r0"> *this one*
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1"> *this one*
<tr class="r1">
<tr class="r0"> *this one*
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1"> *this one*
<tr class="r1">
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Apologies, I have forgotten to add an important part here!

Sometimes my table looks like this:

```
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1">
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1">
<tr class="r0">
<tr class="r1">
```

And in that case I dont need to target anything. So I only need to target it if it looks like the first code example. What's more, these two examples have the exact same classes and ID so there is no way of telling which one is being displayed.

Thanks!

EDIT:

this seems to work, almost

```
tr.r0 + tr.r0 {
    background-color:red;
}

tr.r1 + tr.r1 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2BVRF/2/ maybe i could play around with that a bit. I would just need it to select the preceding element and not the following one :/

Comment: `table tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color:#cecece;
}`

Comment: To clarity, you want to target the first `<tr>` in a group (defined by adjacent `<tr>`'s) with the same class?

Comment: that's correct Marty, so that in the second code exmaple I posted no CSS gets applied :)

Comment: I don't think you can do this in pure CSS, because there is no 'followed by' selector. If there was, you could target all `tr.r0 + tr.r1` that were followed by another `tr.r1` and vice-versa.

Comment: cheers Marty, you wanna put that in an answer then I can close this?

Comment: Could you use a JavaScript solution?

Comment: no dont want to use JS, but I have found that @vitim's solution work well, by exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the second rows but not the first ones.

```
.r0 + .r0,
.r1 + .r1{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

[image]

You can try to match the opposite by doing something like this.

```
.r0 + .r0 + .r1,
.r1 + .r1 + .r0{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

[image]

But you can see that it does not match the first element, because CSS can't match backwards it just match forward or downwards the DOM Tree.

http://jsfiddle.net/62F4N/

---

But there's no limitation if you can javascript http://jsfiddle.net/62F4N/2/

```
var els=document.querySelectorAll('tr.r0,tr.r1');

for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
    var el = els[i];

    if(el.nextElementSibling && el.className==el.nextElementSibling.className){
        el.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vitim, I have found this is the best approach. Although one cannot target the desired row directly, one can in fact do so by excluding the others. Thanks!

Comment: @user1525612 I added a javascript solution as well

Answer (score 1):

```
tr:nth-child (odd){
    /* Your style */
}
```

Comment: thanks, i am so sorry I have forgotten to mention an important part and have updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the :nth-child selector.

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2BVRF/

[EDIT #2: classless]

Hmm, sorry, but there's no way to select the preceding element in CSS. You will need JS to accomplish this task, if the classes must stay the same.

This example uses jQuery, in order to select the preceding element:

http://jsfiddle.net/2BVRF/3/

[EDIT: new conditions of OP]

Unfortunately, given that you need to target one of the two tables, this method would no longer be all that helpful.

You would be better off assigning a class to the table to target the odd rows, which will leave the table you don't want to target alone.

Updated working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2BVRF/1/

Comment: thanks but that won't work as these two tables would have the exact same classes :(

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp you'll want to do this:

```
tr:nth-child(2) {
  /* CSS goes here */
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp for more.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code in jsfiddle. It works fine.

```
.special tr.r0:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:red;
}

.special tr.r1:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the idea for the second case that will handle with pure css but for the `first case` you can use like this

```
tr.r0:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: red;
}
tr.r1:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2BVRF/6/)